# How can long polling be helpfull at all?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, long-integer, polling

I don't understand, how can long polling be helpfull at all if XMLHttpRequest gives no access to partial content???

There is no difference where to wait, on client, or on server. The responce can be shown only upon complete. So, both short polling and long polling appear identical.

For example, if I am writing chat application, I can both send GET requests for normal dynamic service or for Comet service -- the result be identical, because I can't get a content untill servel finish response.

Where is my mistake?

Update 1.

So the only sense of "comet" notion is that servlet (for example) should just wait as much as possible before answering trying never say "no data"?

Then what such interface as CometProcessor in Tomcat API exist for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a new chat line comes in, the server completes the long poll request, and the client issues a new one. So you simulate support for partial content by reissuing the request each time part comes in.

Comment: So what is the difference with "short" poll? In short poll I will also reissue request again and again.

Comment: @Dims, with short polling, if there is no new data you return immediately and the client waits some preset interval hoping there'll be more data next time. with long polling, if there's no data _at all_ waiting, the server keeps the connection open and blocks a response until there's more data to be found.

Comment: Okay, probably I just was expecting something extraordinary from long polling while it is just a simple advice.

Answer (score 1):

The point of long polling is to *emulate* the process of the server pushing data to the client. What makes it an emulation is that the server holds onto the request from the client, such that the server decides when to respond, ie. it appears that the server is in control of data transfer when in fact its not entirely. It is not actually pushing data in the proper sense, hence long polling is only an emulation of push-based transfer.

Once the client receives a response, it immediately sends out another request so that the server is consistently in control of sending data down the pipeline.

Comment: But don't I send another request in short polling too? Then whats the difference?

Comment: The difference is that the server doesn't hold onto the request in short polling, it responds immediately.

Answer (score 0):

With long polling, the server does the "waiting", reducing the number of HTTP connections to set up.  You launch a poll from the client, and then the server stretches out the response as necessary until it's actually got data to return. Thus you don't burden the client with having to start HTTP requests over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

With long-polling, the server returns a **complete** response *as soon as it has some data* (then, as the other answers say, the client issues another request).

So, this technique is quicker than regularly short-polling, where the client would potentially request the data some time after the server had it available.

HTH

Comment: In both polling mechanisms I will reissue request just after I have response to previous. So there is no chance for me to be late with event.

Comment: but with short-polling, there is a greater likelihood of being 'between requests', i.e. in the process of disconnecting/reconnecting => so, slightly slower. Also, more overhead.

Comment: TBH I may have misunderstood your misunderstanding... perhaps your misunderstanding is more fundamental than this. Have your read things like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) ?

Comment: May be I have read this not very carefully but I have. While reading I didn't know the limitations of XMLHttpRequest and was thinking it is possible to receive many responces over long period of waiting time. This was the sense of "long" for me. But since XMLHttpRequest not allows this, I should split time into short portions. Then the sense of "long" disappears. Any server URL waits until it's ready, and no place for some significant longness here...

Comment: I think this conversation isn't working out! I don't understand what you're saying, and I don't think you understand me either. Never mind, and good luck, I'm sure you'll make a workable solution